# LightOpenID with Google new OAuth2 system

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I'd like to implement an OpenID login system for my web application. I'm using LightOpenID for this. I've went to Google and found out that the old (well documented online) OpenID2 system [became old](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID):

> **Important**: Google has deprecated OpenID 2.0 and will shut it down after a migration period. If your app uses OpenID 2.0, the userinfo endpoint, or OAuth 2.0 login (early version), you should migrate your app by the deadlines given in the [migration timetable](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable).

Then, how can I use the same OpenID compliant logic for Google?

Answer (score 0):

Do not get scared, they are migrating services but they are changing names over all. oAuth 2 is the current, secure and new method, you have to make sure that you are not using oAuth 1 and if so, migrate que libraries to 2 version and implement it this way:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect

All this changes are not for security or ageing reasons, they are just to integrate Google + options to gather user info like you do with Facebook.

I would suggest you to implement stand alone Google + login using oAuth 2 because even OpenId official site still is showing version 1 docs: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

It is quiet easy, straight ahead work, no work arounds: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client